# Typescript: recursive iteration leads to different outcome for Array vs Tuple type

Tags: typescript, tuples, typescript-generics

I'm currently working on a function that can accept an array as argument, and I seem to have stumbled on an interface that behaves differently if I pass an array literal/tuple versus the result of a dynamic Array.map call.

It works out great for me because I can now get the compiler to tell the two apart, and so can type the result of the function differently, but I'm not clear on why it's working.

Here is a simplified version of my TS "reducer", where `Elem` is a generic type of each element in the array. In real life, I'm not returning `never`, I'm just doing something different with the Array.map arguments.

```
type Elem<X = unknown, Y = unknown> = {
    x: X;
    y: Y;
}

type Predicate<T extends any> = T extends Elem<infer X, infer Y> ? T : [never, 'could not infer Elem']

type Reducer1<T extends any[], Result extends any[] = []> = 
  T extends []
    ? []
    : T extends [infer Head]
    ? [...Result, Predicate<Head>]
    : T extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
    ? Reducer1<[...Tail], [...Result, Predicate<Head>]>
    : Elem[] extends T ? T : [never, 'could not extend T?']

function Test3<T extends any[]> (
  params: [...Reducer1<T>]
): void {
  return undefined
}

// OK
Test3([{x: '1', y: 1}, {x: 1, y: '1'}])

// FAIL: `is not assignable to parameter of type '[never, "could not extend T?"]'`
Test3(Array(10).map((_, i) => ({ x: i.toString(), y: i })))
```

This function works with an literal but not with a dynamic Array.map result.

Interestingly, if I change the last line of the reducer to `Elem[] extends T ? [never, 'could extend T'] : [never, 'could not extend T?']`, then both types of arguments fail with the first option (suggesting that at some point in the evaluation, TS was able to get `Elem` to extend `T` for the dynamic map result??)

The full details are in the [TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAogNhAtgHgBpQLxQK4DsDWuA9gO64A0UAmpjgcWQHy0DeAsAFBTdQAeAXFFQBuTjyghBVURwC%20nTgHpFUAAoBBAEoAVKAEZOoSFE0QA5tjgBDAE4BZK2DABLXGeS6IvYBFwATAGcoK1wQAG0AXWYsT29fQNgEREioAH4oXUEw3AgANwgbSgByAGMiSz8oYmAoLx9-RKRI1KKIzgAzPBLgZyJcDIgA4D0PWrj-IJDwqKgACjEeMFsrRACsgDpN0wtre0cXNw9GNo4ASkFcomdK9i4eGwhgbBt%20vD8IdtcIP055Dm1BsNZuobDYrCBZnoAAyndaIRyzWYAfUozlOmGYs1u4gEUGc62ARAAysAbK4zLNTuQFtxJHjfqdGZwAUM9LMwixcUU9EVKHS9LJKJzBHo%20YJuUVZBFTgoOMo1FpdAAmQzgaAASVw%20RsPj8Dic5NGdXik1CkWijWSETG9QSunSmSg2TyBWKZQqVSINWNDW0LROnVw3V6-RZwCVRvGCSm5rmNKgSzBqw2m012t1%20oO7m0x045ygl2uUGx90ez1e-g%20Xx%20cmZgKVwNB4MhMLhCORqPRGExJe4uPxhJJZLclOpd1pgmcDKZ-3r7OFUAlYv0guLuNFEnFPKlMo4quMqgefmcJSsPkjttNIAtsUvluQrnaBSEqNwT5s1GYDqgWRy2rd5RwJU1R4m%20z7wEgrSyvKGg6FAADM%207QKYfjYCUBQjPGt4msEZoRGO4imAEljelGV4pFgkScBaWE2jhVHjuIaROicTE8II2ETE6j7PgAEhAVh%20KxbHMWEmzrERJGUIe3wnmeEDIPxgm5ox4gcXRXFhDxH5KX4lDidpGRWM4cDCWx6QoWhGHIGJmzaMZpmULZEmDFJahHnJ566ccjDxmplopD6drMY6zr-ou7pAZ6pG2hk-qyoGwZ9AMQzwReOExjM8yMYmKxrE64mWehNgjDmJz5oWNzxg8TwvHQ7yfDkNZ-GG8GNmCELQrC8JgIiKJ4l2Pbxv2BLEqS5KjvGdJTnIjK7q185cjyy4CkK67LhKO7QSosG6AALEhJjfFZNgRrRQXkfh8aSXAMUZXhtAMTRjGcQkDEiaJZlMepF3cWBOkCUJfk8Okzk3cA0keaeXmAypH0-WRf3vlAun6Zshn2SZX3iBZx3FRGzmY45BVbK5t2Q7J0MKd5UTA9wggQVaGnBaDf6uhFgGVEFGStD%20Tps4UHMeiB3N%20lBe4cIlPTJWGe3pVxmWYvGuXJiTLmofjRzlRcVxVYxNXlvVVZNb8dZDHt7XNl1ba9R2A0YnMvZ8JOo1DhNVJTZO07zYCFscktvKbiua0iht27SkAA) with all the details; if you scroll over the various errors it should help clarify what I'm referring to.

(Part 1 is just a dummy example with `T extends Elem[]` showing no errors. Part 2 uses `Elem[] extends T` without any recursive iteration, showing it fail for both argument types. And Parts 3 and 4 are the examples I was talking about in this message.)

Sorry for the somewhat contrived example, hopefully it's clear. Thanks in advance!!!

edit: for context, [this second playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogNhAtgHgBpQLxQK4DsDWuA9gO64A0UAmpjgcWQHy0DeAsAFBTdQAeAXFFQBuTjyghBVUVx4AvQQAoAJgENgqwagCUmZgDciAS2WcAvp06hIUAMKq4cAEaqAxvmQAVKBF7AIuMoAzlCquCDMWN6+-oEh8EjIRrgAZhAATkKUyWmZVMwA-FDeggDauBD6GZQA5CmqRgjKUClGvBDNqunpqiBQ1hAAtK4AFhDuNQC6lhwA9LN2ADIA8gDKMABKxctQGzAAgotQiwCSAGIwUACq64O2++tQ-NpW4NAbHdiuGchiPNF+ALBULhUqTch-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-QydIiEyJxxlUbAgmgE4akQHAggbYAxigEhVNwON3x6AzwxSNSI1tIV8CgOQMKwnDKwI4jSPIqiaL0ESGJ4JijBYtiJMs7jBJ4fiYu4YTRKgGTEA09IpOS2T5MU9COEw8TFFKYLuCYmp8JqeKJEEfDKsS5QxMimMMpkxxzHIYq+GqyqqzKirsTqwQUrS5qstQyYXjmBYjNLOAujgEBKBUhzXC0nTmjTKBSyCMjgFGVMIGAEgIACPgQWaNy8qworsVK8ruq6-qlHqqBxM4yyRta1D2puh6+MEXraqehq3qawKWrksbtCAA) link includes how I actually take advantage of the behaviour, to type-check a callback on a fixed and a dynamic array for the same function

Comment: AFAIK, it is impossible to use Reducer type with dynamic arrays. Btw, it is better to use `Callback` name instead of `Predicate`. Some time ago I also used Predicate, but you predicate is a function which returns boolean.

Comment: In order to get rid of type error you should use type assertion if you use Reducer and dynamic array. If TS does not know the length of dynamic array, it is impossible to figure out when recursion should stop

Comment: Hi @captain-yossarian, thanks for the reply. I just added a second playground link for some extra context (ran out of characters here, so added the link to my original post). I'm not actually trying to get rid of the error; I'm using the behaviour to my advantage; it means I can handle both fixed and dynamic arrays with that reducer. It seems to be working ok, but let me know if you see any issues with it.

Comment: ah your comment provided me with a hint: you said "If TS does not know the length of dynamic array, it is impossible to figure out when recursion should stop" - it looks like with a dynamic array, the recursion keeps going until T is an empty array `[]`, at which point it fails `Elem[] extends T` and falls through to the `never`?

Comment: Could you please write exact question and I will try to answer it